# make pwsh print profile loading time at startup

Tags: powershell

My `pwsh` sometimes prints

```
PowerShell 7.3.9
Loading personal and system profiles took NNNNms.
PS C:\Users\shynur>
```

at startup, sometimes it doesn't print the profile loading time (the 2nd line).

How to change my profile (`C:\Users\shynur\Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1`) to have it printed each time at startup?

---

MRE:

```
# Profile.ps1
sleep 13
```

Comment: Please share the contents of this `Profile.ps1` How else could we tell what to change  ?

Comment: @Luuk I believe there's no need to share the content of my profile.  The message will be printed when pwsh takes too long time to load profile.  You can test it easily, say put a `sleep 10` into your profile.

Comment: Just adding `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500` should do, when I read: [I believe this threshold to be 500 ms](https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/PowerShell/language/variable/automatic/profile#:~:text=I%20believe%20this%20threshold%20to%20be%20500%20ms), But I cannot find an official source for that ...

Comment: @Luuk You can make it an answer.  I'll upvote it because I had the same idea when I read that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `Loading personal and system profiles took ...` message is only displayed if the combined loading time of all [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) exceeds [500 ms.](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/d3c91d0e6325cfcb0632eb9dc1e6a577fd062359/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs#L1915) (as of PowerShell 7.4)

This threshold is *hard-coded*, so your only choice is to *re-create this message yourself* if the combined load time is less than 500 milliseconds, but there are two challenges:

- By the time your - current-host, current-user-specific - `$PROFILE` file executes, all the *other* profile files - if any - have already been run; more on that below.
- You won't be able to tell *with certainty* whether PowerShell will print the message, as you have no access to the result of its time measurement.

  - The measurement happens in the context of PowerShell's telemetry, but its [public API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.telemetry.internal.telemetryapi), as of PowerShell 7.3.10, exposes just one member, [`TelemetryAPI.TraceMessage()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.telemetry.internal.telemetryapi.tracemessage#microsoft-powershell-telemetry-internal-telemetryapi-tracemessage-1(system-string-0))
  - In other words: you may get *two* messages, and the measurements aren't guaranteed to be the same.

---

To *approximate* PowerShell's own profile-loading time measurement, you have two options:

- **Option A**:

  - Save a timestamp at the *start* of the all-users, all-hosts profile file, `$PROFILE.AllUsersAllHosts`
  - At the *end* of your `$PROFILE` file (`$PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost`), which is the *last* to load, measure and print the time elapsed since the saved timestamp.
- **Option B**:

  - At the *end* of your `$PROFILE` file (`$PROFILE.CurrentUserCurrentHost`), measure the time elapses *since the PowerShell process was created*.

**Caveats**:

- Option A will *underestimate* the actual loading time (by the time you start measuring the first profile file has already been loaded and parsed)
- Option B will *overestimate* it (starting measurement at process creation time includes the startup time of the process itself, before it starts loading profiles).
- Either way, implementing your custom measurement obviously *increases load time*.

---

**Implementation** of **option B**:

```bash
# Your $PROFILE file

# ... 

# At the VERY END, measure how much time has elapsed since process creation.
# THIS MEASUREMENT OBVIOUSLY ADDS TO THE OVERALL LOAD TIME.
if (($msSinceProcessCreation = ([datetime]::UtcNow - (Get-Process -Id $PID).StartTime.ToUniversalTime()).TotalMilliSeconds) -gt 500) {
  'Loading personal and system profiles took {0:F0}ms.' -f $msSinceProcessCreation
}
```

Note:

- The impact of the custom measurement on overall loading time is nontrivial.
- On my M1 Mac, for instance, the custom measurement *overestimates* the load time by 200+ ms. - on the flip side, it is a more realistic measurement of the time it takes until the session is ready for interactive user input.